# How to add script reference on master page?

Tags: list, javascript, visual-studio, custom-masterpage, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have applied master page using JavaScript in my **SharePoint Hosted App**. This script reference is added on **default.aspx**. Now I want to add script reference on master page which I have applied so that it will work on all hierarchy. Suppose I have two links

> https://domain.com/site/appname/default.aspx
>
> https://domain.com/site/appname/Lists/listname.aspx

I have tried with below reference

```
<script src="../Scripts/FieldToHide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but t works only for **default.aspx** page but not under **Lists** folder

So Is it possible to provide such reference. If yes how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the full absolute path to the JS file maybe?

Comment: are you inserting on custom master page or seattle?

Comment: custom master page

Comment: @MrunalShidurkar Specify a system master page for this site and all sites that inherit from it : set your custom master page here also. Site Setting -> Master Page

Comment: is it working @MrunalShidurkar?

Comment: I am setting it there but js is loaded only once with masted page. it will not work for lists

Comment: have you enabled system master page?

Comment: I am hosting SharePoint hosted app so I can't  access Site settings

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your SharePoint has [MDS activated](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/minimum-download-strategy-mds-in-sharepoint-2013)?

(You can most probably test that by reloading the page. If your script works on freshly loaded pages but not after "normal" navigation - check MDS...)

If MDS is active, you'll need to make sure that you register a namespace (using `Type.registerNamespace`) and possibly register your module-init (using `window.RegisterModuleInit`)

[Wictor Wilén has a nice post on this.](http://www.wictorwilen.se/the-correct-way-to-execute-javascript-functions-in-sharepoint-2013-mds-enabled-sites)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution
Below code works fine for me

```
<scripts><asp:ScriptReference Path="<%$SPUrl:../../Scripts/FieldToHide.js%>"></asp:ScriptReference></scripts>
```

**Note:** Above code be placed inside **asp:ScriptManager** tag

Answer (score 0):

You could simply edit your custom master page (ex. mymaster.html) with Sharepoint Designer.

and add the link to your script.

ex.

```
<script language="javascript" src="/StyleLibrary/scripts/yourscript.js"></script>
```

then publish your custom master page.

Comment: This solution is not working

Comment: did you debug with F12 on the browser to see if the script was downloaded?

Comment: script is downloading. But While navigating to list page it give 404 error for the same script.

Comment: so it means that you should check where the script is and what you wrote in src="". What do you have in src="" in the master page ?

Comment: This was actually my question. Script Path should be work on all pages

Comment: so what do you have in the script path in the master page? If you put  the script as I wrote for example in /styleLibrary/script/yourscript.js it gets downloaded in all pages that use the master page

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a script file to your master page this way.

Grab a file from the Farm Level site (root)

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="UniqueIdForYourFile22" Language="javascript" Name="NameOfYourScriptFile.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

You can also grab the file from the site collection level. This is from the SiteAsset.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="UniqueIdForYourFile29" runat="server" Name="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/AngularJS/angular.js" Language="javascript" OnDemand="false" />
```